# phpmyadmin - Navigation panel and icons are missing

Tags: phpmyadmin

Help! Recently the navigation panel has gone missing from phpmyadmin.
Except by using SQL queries I can't navigate around the databases and tables.
I haven't changed anything intentionally. Is there something I'm missing about hiding and unhiding the navigation panel?
I'm using php v4.4.6deb with MySQL Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 - Debian 10

Answer (score 0):

Dumbo! Turns out the main window left edge had been expanded to occlude the navigation panel. Or perhaps it was the right edge of the navigation panel had been moved to the left edge! It was there all the time.